# How do I password protected a zip folder in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, zip

I want to create a zip folder with a password which will ask for a password while extracting the zip folder using node.js on the server side. There is one example of zip folder creation without a password but how can I make it password protected?

Below is the code to create a password-protected zip. So, inside the demo folder, I have the list of files and those files I wanted to zip in one folder. I have created `test.zip` inside the `xyz` folder and the zip is getting created but it will not ask for a password while extracting that zip. Instead, it is asking for a password while opening the individual files after extracting. I hope you can understand my question.

```js
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  zip = spawn('zip',['-P', 'password' , '-r','./xyz/test.zip', `./demo`]);
  zip .on('exit', function(code) {
    console.log("zip with password protected successfully");
})
```

Comment: You need to check the `code` argument in your `on('exit')` callback: you cannot assume that that operation was successful just because the process exited.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **You cannot**.

Zip files (`PKZip` files, specifically) do not support whole-archive encryption or filename encryption: only individual files within the archive can be encrypted - and the standard encryption scheme (`ZipCrypto`) [and is considered insecure today](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028074139/https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Emike/zipattacks.pdf).

More modern versions of the PKZip specification support AES encryption and also encrypting the file header, however zip files using this version **are not** supported by (in my experience) most software used today, including Microsoft Windows (Windows 11 still doesn't support AES-encrypted zip files, for example).

In your case specifically, I see you're using the `zip` command-line executable, which (depending on your *nix distro) does not support AES encryption, nor header encryption - only ZipCrypto on a per-file basis.

Comment: You mean to say it's not possible to do whole-archive encryption right? if so, Is there any other way to do whole-archive encryption instead of only individual files within the archive.

Comment: @SwapnilShingole Not with `.zip` files, no. Why not use a more modern format like 7Zip instead?